# Is this a valid reduction of Ingham's upper bound for prime gaps?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

> Let $p_n$ denote the $n^{th}$ prime number. [Ingham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Ingham) showed that:
>
> $$p_{n+1} - p_n \lt K p_n^{\frac{5}{8}}$$
>
> where $K$ is a fixed positive integer, is an [upper bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Upper_bounds) for the prime gaps.
>
> (A.E.Ingham, On the difference between consecutive primes, Quart. J. Math. Oxford Ser. vol. 8 (1937) pp. 255-266)
>
> I would like to know if the following manipulations would be valid to reduce the value $\frac{5}{8}$ up to $\frac{1}{8}$. Initially I cannot see it, but surely there is an error and I would like to learn where the mistake is:

1. Both sides to the eighth:

$$(p_{n+1} - p_n)^8 \lt K^8 p_n^{5}$$

2. Def. $K_2 = K^8$ a new fixed constant $K_2 \gt K$:

$$(p_{n+1} - p_n)^8 \lt K_2 p_n^{5}$$

3. By [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), we know that $p_n^{5}$ can be replaced as follows:

$$p_n^{5}= 5K^{'} + p_n$$

For a given positive constant $K^{'}$. Thus:

$$(p_{n+1} - p_n)^8 \lt K_2 (5K^{'} + p_n)$$

And the right side of the inequality can be replaced as follows:

$$(p_{n+1} - p_n)^8 \lt K_2 (5K^{'} + p_n) = (K_2 \cdot 5K^{'}) + K_2 p_n$$

4. Def. $K_3 = K_2 \cdot 5K^{'}$ an even bigger new fixed constant $K_3 \gt K_2$:

$$(p_{n+1} - p_n)^8 \lt K_3 + K_2 p_n$$

5. As $K_3 \gt K_2$, it is also true that:

$$(p_{n+1} - p_n)^8 \lt K_3 + K_2 p_n  \lt K_3 + K_3 p_n = K_3 (1+p_n) \lt K_3 (2p_n) = (2K_3) \cdot p_n$$

6. Def. $K_4 = 2K_3$ as an even bigger new fixed constant $K_4 \gt K_3$:

$$(p_{n+1} - p_n)^8 \lt K_4 \cdot p_n$$

7. Now we make again the $8^{th}$ root in both sides:

$$p_{n+1} - p_n \lt K_4^{\frac{1}{8}} \cdot p_n^{\frac{1}{8}}$$

8. Def. $K_5 = K_4^{\frac{1}{8}}$ as a new fixed constant. In this case $K_5 \lt K_4$ but still fixed and positive:

$$p_{n+1} - p_n \lt K_5 \cdot p_n^{\frac{1}{8}}$$

Thus, if the manipulations and redefinition of constants are correct, Ingham's result might be reduced from a $\frac{5}{8}$ exponent to a $\frac{1}{8}$ for a different fixed constant $K_5$.

> This manipulations are easy, so surely I am making a forbidden step, I think that the use of Fermat's Little Theorem is valid, but not sure if redefining the fixed constants is correct, or moving the power of eight is valid or not. Indeed the last constant $K_5$ is smaller than the previous one, that also could be an error. Any explanations and insights are very appreciated.

Comment: The use of Fermat's little theorem is incorrect, as $K'$ depends on $p_n$ and is not constant. Example: $2^5-2 = 5\cdot6$ (so $K' = 6$) while $3^5-3 = 5\cdot48$ (so $K' = 48$) and of course $p \mapsto (p^5-p)/5$ is increasing with $p$.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood it but wouldn't you want the constant to work for all large $n$? In (3), you define $K'$ that depends on $p_n$. As $n$ increases, that $K'$ also increases.

Comment: @JordanPayette very appreciated! ... so it was there, indeed that step is critical.

Comment: @AlexMacedo thanks for the feedback! yes as Jordan also notice. That was the failure.

Comment: @JordanPayette by the way if you have some seconds to put your comment as an answer I could accept the answer.

Comment: @JordanPayette as a side note, then that step could be partially true for instance as far as $5K^{'} \lt K_2$ because it is possible to replace $5K^{'}$ by the fixed $K_2$ and then continue the reductions. But clearly is not possible for values over $K_2$, it is possible to apply some similar rules, but not for all the possible values of $K^{'}$ anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is in the use of Fermat's little theorem. Indeed, the map

$$ K' : \mathbb{P} \to \mathbb{N} : p \mapsto \frac{p^5 - p}{5}$$

is not constant (contrary to what was claimed in the argument) and is in fact unbounded from above. So in the end, the obtained estimate is true if one keeps in mind that $K_5$ is not a constant, but a 'fast' increasing function of $p_n$.

Comment: thanks for your answer! may I ask a final question? (basically the same one in the comments): Would that step be partially true for instance as far as we bound $5K^{'}<K_2$? for example in that case it is possible to replace $5K^{′}$ by the fixed $K_2$ and then continue the reductions. So **even** if $K^{'}$ is variable, as long as it is bounded by $K_2$ it can be replaced by the fixed value $K_2$ so the final expression remains as a fixed constant. That would be a partial result, not valid for values over $K_2$ but true as long as we can bound $K^{'}$. Does it make sense?

Comment: @iadvd Yes, of course, considering that the rest of your argument is correct. You can take as $K_5$ any function of the form $K(10F)^{1/8}$ where $F(p)$ is any function greater than the function $K'(p)$ from my answer. In particular, $F$ could be a 'stair function'.

Comment: it was very helpful thank you! just in case you were interested, I have added a new question assuming the bounding condition https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2239481/is-this-a-valid-partial-refinement-of-inghams-upper-bound-for-prime-gaps