# Is this a valid partial refinement of Ingham's upper bound for prime gaps?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

This is a follow-up question [from this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2238063/is-this-a-valid-reduction-of-inghams-upper-bound-for-prime-gaps) that was kindly answered by @JordanPayette. The corrections were applied for this solution.

Let $p_n$ denote the $n^{th}$ prime number. [Ingham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Ingham) showed that:

$$p_{n+1} - p_n \lt K p_n^{\frac{5}{8}}$$

where $K$ is a fixed positive integer, is an [upper bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Upper_bounds) for the prime gaps.

(A.E.Ingham, On the difference between consecutive primes, Quart. J. Math. Oxford Ser. vol. 8 (1937) pp. 255-266)

> I would like to know if the following easy manipulations would be valid to reduce the value $\frac{5}{8}$ up to $\frac{1}{8}$. The steps on $\color{blue}{blue\ color}$ have been verified in the [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2238063/is-this-a-valid-reduction-of-inghams-upper-bound-for-prime-gaps), so if possible I would appreciate very much if somebody could kindly verify if the rest are also accurate (the questions are at the end).

1. $\color{blue}{(verified)}$ Both sides to the eighth:

$$(p_{n+1} - p_n)^8 \lt K^8 p_n^{5}$$

2. $\color{blue}{(verified)}$ Def. $K_2 = K^8$ a new fixed constant $K_2 \gt K$:

$$(p_{n+1} - p_n)^8 \lt K_2 p_n^{5}$$

3. $\color{blue}{(verified)}$ By [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), we know that $p_n^{5}$ can be replaced as follows}:

$$p_n^{5}= 5K^{'} + p_n$$

For a given positive **unbounded** constant $K^{'}$. Thus:

$$(p_{n+1} - p_n)^8 \lt K_2 (5K^{'} + p_n)$$

But (credits for the following explanation to @JordanPayette) the map

$$ K' : \mathbb{P} \to \mathbb{N} : p \mapsto \frac{p^5 - p}{5}$$

is not constant and unbounded from above.

---

> $\color{red}{From\ this\ point\ ahead\ the\ manipulations\ need\ to\ be\ verified}$.

The right side of the inequality can be replaced as follows:

$$(p_{n+1} - p_n)^8 \lt K_2 (5K^{'} + p_n) = (K_2 \cdot 5K^{'}) + K_2 p_n$$

Our partial refinement will be true only if the constants are fixed and bounded, so we need to add a condition to handle $(K_2 \cdot 5K^{'})$. So let us assume the following condition:

> Condition 1: $$ p_n^{5}-p_n = 5K^{'} \lt K_2 = K^8$$
>
> So from now on, the partial refinement will be valid only those primes $p_n$ whose value $p_n^{5}-p_n$ is bounded by the eighth power of Ingham's $K$ constant.

4. Def. $K_3 = K_2^2$ an even bigger new fixed constant $K_3 \gt K_2$:

$$(p_{n+1} - p_n)^8 \lt K_3 + K_2 p_n$$

5. As $K_3 \gt K_2$, it is also true that:

$$(p_{n+1} - p_n)^8 \lt K_3 + K_2 p_n  \lt K_3 + K_3 p_n = K_3 (1+p_n) \lt K_3 (2p_n) = (2K_3) \cdot p_n$$

6. Def. $K_4 = 2K_3$ as an even bigger new fixed constant $K_4 \gt K_3$:

$$(p_{n+1} - p_n)^8 \lt K_4 \cdot p_n$$

7. Now we make again the $8^{th}$ root in both sides:

$$p_{n+1} - p_n \lt K_4^{\frac{1}{8}} \cdot p_n^{\frac{1}{8}}$$

8. Finally, def. $K_5 = K_4^{\frac{1}{8}}$ as a new fixed constant. In this case $K_5 \lt K_4$ but still fixed and positive:

$$p_{n+1} - p_n \lt K_5 \cdot p_n^{\frac{1}{8}}$$

Only valid under Condition 1:

$$ p_n^{5}-p_n \lt K^8$$

being $K$ the original Ingham's $K$ constant.

> Thus, if the manipulations and redefinition of constants are correct:
>
> 1. If $ p_n^{5}-p_n \lt K^8$:
>
> $$p_{n+1} - p_n \lt K_5 p_n^{\frac{1}{8}}$$
>
> for a fixed constant $K_5 = K_4^{\frac{1}{8}}=(2K_3)^{\frac{1}{8}}=(2K_2^2)^{\frac{1}{8}}=(2(K^8)^2)^{\frac{1}{8}}=2^{\frac{1}{8}}K^2$, and
>
> 2. In the rest of unbounded cases remains as the original Ingham's expression:
>
> $$p_{n+1} - p_n \lt K p_n^{\frac{5}{8}}$$

I would like to ask the following questions:

1. Are the manipulations so far correct? It is based on Fermat's Little Theorem and the redefinition of the fixed constant.
2. If it is initially correct, is the refinement significant? It is bounded, so just valid for a finite range of prime numbers $p_n=2,3,5..$ as long as $ p_n^{5}-p_n \lt K^8$ but it could help to verify other open questions at least for the bounded range of primes covered by the refinement.

Comment: It is far from being clear why you think the Fermat little theorem should be useful here.. It seems JordanPayette already answered why the argument you are trying to use is wrong.

Comment: @user1952009 please let me disagree with that observation: 1) as per JordanPayette's answer to my final question in the comments to his/her solution, he/she agrees with my use of FLT **once it is bounded** and provided indeed other solutions for a good bound. Mine in this question is the simplest bounded solution according to that conversation. And I believe that a refinement of the bound of prime gaps (even if it is applied for a finite range of primes) could be of interest.

Comment: It is obvious that the Fermat little theorem won't give a miraculous better bound for the prime gap.

Comment: Come on.. In $(p_{n+1} - p_n)^8 \lt K_3 + K_2 p_n$ obviously $K_3,K_2$ are functions of $n$.

Comment: @user1952009 sorry, but they are not : $K_3=K_2^2$ and $K_2=K^8$, so $K_3=(K^8)^2$ where $K$ is the original fixed Ingham's $K$ constant. So all of them are again fixed manipulations of the original $K$ constant, thus they are fixed.

Comment: They are functions of $n$, that's what Jordan explained to you.

Comment: Jordan's answer : "keep in mind that $K_5$ is not a constant, but a fast increasing function of $p_n$"

Comment: @user1952009 but that is because if you see the former question, I was dragging the FLT unbounded constant up to the end of the proof, so the rest of constant up to the final $K_5$ were including the dependence of $n$. For that reason I modified the step $3$ on this current question, avoiding the step of the constant that is function of $n$ and for that reason from that point ahead now the constants are again safe and do not depend on $n$. I modified step $3$ to avoid that situation.

Comment: Yes but no. ${}{}{}$

Comment: I agree with with @user1952009. I don't know what is an 'unbounded constant'. What I (implicitly) claimed is that if you restrain your considerations to primes which are smaller than some value $p$, then the function $K'$ is bounded from above on the interval $[2, p]$ by some $p$-dependent constant $C(p)$. Hence, by *only* considering primes $p_n \in [2, p]$, your whole argument is correct and you *do* get that $p_{n+1} - p_n \le (10C(p))^{1/8}K p_n^{1/8}$. Indeed, $C(p)$ doesn't depend on $n$ but the maximal value of $n$ allowed in this estimate does depend on $p$, hence the 'Yes but no'.

Comment: @JordanPayette thanks for the feedback again! probably my words are not well selected (non English native speaker here), I was referring to your former answer: my "unbounded constant" tried to mean your "the map K' (...) is not constant (...) and is in fact unbounded from above" specially the "unbounded from above" part. Probably the words are not correct but I am referring to that same point. Does it make sense?

Comment: @JordanPayette and I agree with all your comment, indeed what you write is what I did in the above proof, (specifically at step $3$), so I would dare to say that is just a problem of my way of expressing this in English. If "yes but no" means that, then I fully agree with both of you as well. :)